# How can I handle errors in loading an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, error-handling

I have an `<iframe>` that other sites can include so their users can `POST` a form back to my site. I'd like to handle gracefully the cases where my site is down or my server can't serve the `<iframe>` contents (that is, a response timeout or a 4xx or 5xx error).  I tried adding an `onError` to the `<iframe>` object, but that didn't seem to do anything:

```
showIFrame = function() {
  var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  iframe.id = 'myIFrame';
  iframe.src = 'http://myserver.com/someURLThatFailsToLoad';
  iframe.onError = iframe.onerror = myHandler;
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);
};

myHandler = function(error) {
  document.getElementById('myIFrame').style.display = 'none';
  console.error('Error loading iframe contents: ' + error);
  return true;
};
```

If my server returns a `404` I just get the contents of the not-found page in my `<iframe>`. In fact, that error handler isn't ever triggered. Is there a way to make this work?

(I'm currently testing in Chrome, but I'd like it to also work for FF and IE >= 7.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To detect whether your server is down or not, you can include an empty script file from your own domain. When the server is down, the `onerror` event handler will fire:

```
var el = document.createElement('script');
el.onerror = errorFunction;
el.src = "somebogusscript.js?" + new Date().getTime();
document.body.appendChild(el);
```

Note: don't forget to add a random string to the `src` attribute to avoid the client using a cached version (which could stop a look at the server at all).

Comment: sorry - great point, though I had already accounted for this. See the update: `iframe.onError = iframe.onerror = myHandler;`

Comment: Most browsers do not allow XHR requests cross-domain. This is Javascript that I provide to other sites. Indeed, the cross-domain restrictions of XHR HTTP are exactly why I'm using an `<iframe>` at all here.

Comment: it appears this approach works with a script element, but not with an iframe.

Comment: @jsleuth You can first test if your server is down and then import the iframe.

Comment: @MarcelKorpel True enough.  What I meant is the iframe element appears not to honor the onerror callback, at least in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could try `onErrorUpdate` for the event handler? I couldn't see an `onError` handler for iFrames. If that doesn't work, you could try `onLoad` and then check the source of the iframe or the title of it for a 404 message.

Such as:
`if (frameDoc.title == 'title the server sends for 404') {`

---

Source:

http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/166288-catch-404-when-using-iframe

iFrame Methods: http://www.java2s.com/Code/HTMLCSSReference/HTML-Tag-Reference/iframeJavaScriptMethods.htm

iFrame Properties: http://www.java2s.com/Code/HTMLCSSReference/HTML-Tag-Reference/iframeJavaScriptProperties.htm

Comment: This could work for the 404 case, but I'm really concerned with the case where the request times out -- that is, when my servers go down.

Comment: Would `onTimeError` trigger in that case? I think that may only work in IE though which is a shame.

Comment: not see onErrorUpdate in all links you provided :(

Answer (score 1):

One technique is to set a JavaScript timeout when you make the request.  If your timeout fires before the iframe onload event, the content didn't load.  You could then set iframe.src to about:blank, delete, or reuse the iframe.