# can I catch exception of Iframe in parent window of Iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, exception

I have an IFrame in a page and IFrame has some JavaScript. At run time JavaScript in IFrame gives exception which i want to catch on parent window. How to do that?

```
<html> 
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var frm123 = document.getElementById("frm123"); 
frm123.contentWindow.onerror = function() { 
    alert('error caught'); 
} 
function loadData() { 
    var oRTE = document.getElementById("frm123").contentWindow.document;
    oRTE.open(); 
    oRTE.write(txt123.value);
    oRTE.close();
} 
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 
<input type="button" onclick="loadData();" value="load"> 
<input type="text" id="txt123"> 
<iframe id = "frm123" > 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Post code and exception message

Answer (score 39):

The answer depends on whether or not you have control of the iframe code, and whether or not it is the same domain.

If same domain then you can do the following to set the error handling function from the wrapping document:

```
document.getElementById("myiframe").contentWindow.onerror=function() {
    alert('error!!');
    return false;
}
```

make sure you wait for the iframe to finish loading before setting the error handler.

If it's not the same domain but you have control of the iframe content (both domains are under your control), you can communicate with the outer frame by using a cross domain communication framework (google it or build it yourself), i.e. catch the error in the iframe by setting the onerror handler from within the iframe and send it through the framework to the outer document.

If it's not the same domain and you don't have control of the iframe, there's no way for the outer document to know what's going on inside it because of security constraints.

Comment: And what I can do if exception will happen during page loading?

Comment: then you will have a problem since you can't control that externally.

Answer (score 4):

There may be few possible causes for `.onError()` function not to work it may be because of cross domain URL's for this you should implement a check before actulally laoding the `iFrame` and for that use

```
var url = "google.com"
var loading_url = "/empty.html"
document.getElementById("iframe").src = loading_url;
$.ajax({
url: url,
type: 'GET',
complete: function(e, xhr, settings){
     if(e.status === 200){
          document.getElementById("iframe").src = url;
     }
  }
});
```

This will not work cross domain, the status code is 0 in those cases.

One more thing to check is `.onError()` handler please check from below sample if it matches your conditions

[How can I handle errors in loading an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705083/how-can-i-handle-errors-in-loading-an-iframe)

There are many other options or tweaks to handle this kind of errors :

`if (frameDoc.title == 'title of page after expection occur')`

will also do the work using on `.onLoad()` event of iFrame.

Answer (score 2):

The ***only*** way is if the frame is on the same domain, in which case you can do, from parent:

```
iframe.contentWindow.onerror = function(){
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var frm123 = document.getElementById("frm123");
frm123.contentWindow.onerror = function(){     alert('error caught'); }

function loadData()
{
 var oRTE = document.getElementById("frm123").contentWindow.document;
    oRTE.open();
    oRTE.write(txt123.value);
    oRTE.close();}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" onclick="loadData();" value="load">
<input type="text" id="txt123">
<iframe id = "frm123">
</body>
</html>

Comment: @ArifHasan Write above code in your question so another can help you