# iFrame remove error and replace with custom message

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

When you load a iFrame from a external website, but it's unreachable.

Is it possible to remove the normal iFrame error that says that it cannot load the page and replace it with a custom text?

Comment: what do you mean by unreachable??

Comment: @MilindAnantwar for example when a page is error 404'd, I guess

Comment: Yes a 404 error. When your running a internal website and try to load a external website within the iFrame. But to hide the error when there is no internet.

Comment: Check out the suggestions at the bottom of this page:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705083/how-can-i-handle-errors-in-loading-an-iframe

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use a XMLHTTPrequest to load the content of the `iframe` (or use JQuery to make it easier). There you can check for errors sent by the server.

Comment: can anyone give an Example of this procedure?