# Open 2nd src In Iframe If 1st src Is Not Responding?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

I am using the below code to embed a external web page to my site...

```
<frame src="1st-Web-Page"></iframe>
```

But some time `1st-Web-Page` is not available like server is down then I want to redirect `1st-Web-Page` to `2nd-Web-Page` in Iframe src.

In real I want to hit `1st-Web-Page` for only 30sec and if that page is not available or loaded in 30sec then open `2nd-Web-Page` instead of it.

Please not that I can only use JavaScript code but if you have any other code like JQuery or PHP then also share with me. So Can I do it?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705083/how-can-i-handle-errors-in-loading-an-iframe

Comment: @drkunibar I didnt try that because I want a time delay. Can you update that code as per my requirement and share here or the below one is working properly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function who check is Domain is availible.

```
 <?php

           if (isDomainAvailible('1st-Web-Page'))
           {
                   echo '<iframe src="1st-Web-Page"></iframe>';
           }
           else
           {
                   echo '<iframe src="2st-Web-Page"></iframe>';
           }

           //returns true, if domain is availible, false if not
           function isDomainAvailible($domain, $timeout = '30')
           {
                   //check, if a valid url is provided
                   if(!filter_var($domain, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
                   {
                           return false;
                   }

                   //initialize curl
                   $curlInit = curl_init($domain);
                   curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,$timeout);
                   curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
                   curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
                   curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

                   //get answer
                   $response = curl_exec($curlInit);

                   curl_close($curlInit);

                   if ($response) return true;

                   return false;
           }
?>
```

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/USERNAME/public_html/AL/index.php on line 10`