# check for "server not found" error with events from an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Ok lets make it simple. I am testing this code which is ran from console:

```
var asd = document.createElement('iframe');
asd.style.width = "0px";
asd.style.height = "0px";
asd.style.display = "none";
asd.src = "http://www.ksdfksdfe33.com/";
document.body.appendChild(asd);
```

This piece of code creates an iframe, hides it, and loads a website which is not exists on the internet (http://www.ksdfksdfe33.com/ for instance). now the point is that I want to do something (here it is `alert`) if the website gives me the error `server not found`.

```
asd.onSOMETHING = function(){window.alert('not loaded');};
```

I want this code do something (eg `alert`) for me if the website gave the error `server not found` now the question is: which event should I use? Ive tried using `onerror`, `onchange`, `onabort` non of them works, and also `asd` does not have `onunload` event.
What should I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I handle errors in loading an iframe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705083/how-can-i-handle-errors-in-loading-an-iframe)

Comment: @kmsdev the problem is that i dont have access to that domain. its cross-origin. Your mentioned case has access to its domain, mine not.

Comment: I am sorry, you can't avoid the cross-origin except if the target website allows it. Anyway you should update your question and include that and any other information which makes sense within the own question.

Comment: @kmsdev assume that target website allows cross-origin framing.

Comment: I think the better (the only) thing you can do is to check for the target server's answer through server side. It's easy and it will avoid any kind of problems. The idea is to check in server side through ajax and work with the response.